# GC gets triggered often

Tags: java, garbage-collection

I would like to understand why the GC gets triggered even though I have plenty of heap left unused.. I have allocated 1.7 GB of RAM. I still see 10% of GC CPU usage often.

I use this - `-XX:+UseG1GC` with Java 17

[image]

Comment: That’s very unusual. Are you sure, you have no other memory or gc related options specified?

Comment: @Holger Why do you think it is unusual, this is pretty standard for regional garbage collectors like G1GC.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel the graph indicates that the first garbage collection was deferred until the entire heap was full, which is unusual for a *concurrent* garbage collector. Second, having more than 10% CPU load, sometimes almost 20%, for a heap having less than 300MB used, is very high.

Comment: @Holger Or something happened that required a lot of memory (and CPU) initially, which could not yet be GC-ed, and then "normal" operation took over.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel there’s not even an attempt for GC before that but even if there was such a series of allocations with not even a single object being collectible, it would still be *unusual*. But why waste our time with speculations when the OP didn’t come back to provide more information?

Comment: Not sure what kind of additional info you were expecting.

Answer (score 1):

JVMs will always have some gc threads running (unless you use Epsilon GC which perform no gc, I do not recommend using this unless you know why you need it), because the JVM manages memory for you.

Heap in G1 is divided two spaces: **young** and **old**. All objects are created in young space. When the young space fills (it always do eventually, unless you are developing zero garbage), it will trigger some gc cleaning unreferenced objects from the young and promoting some objects which are still referenced to old.

Those spikes in the right screenshot will correspond to young collection events (where unreferenced objects get cleaned). Young space is always much more small than the old space. So it fills frequently. That is why you see those spikes regarding there is much more memory free.

*Disclaimer*: This is a really very high level explanation of memory management in the JVM. Some important concepts have been not mentioned.

You can read more about G1GC collector [here](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/tutorials/tutorials-1876574.html)

Also take a look at [jstat](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/specs/man/jstat.html) tool which will help you understand what is happening in your heap.